# Using OrdinalEnconder() to transform columns with predefined numerical values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, encode

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({'department': ['operations','operations','support','logics', 'sales'],
                   'salary': ["low", "medium", "medium", "high", "high"],
                   'tenure': [5,6,6,8,5],
                  })
df


   department  salary  tenure
0  operations     low       5
1  operations  medium       6
2     support  medium       6
3      logics    high       8
4       sales    high       5
```

I want to encode the salary feature as ['low', 1], ['Medium', 2], ['High', 3]. Or, ['low', 0], ['Medium', 1], ['High', 2]  - not sure if the exact values make a difference for the further use in a classification algorithm such as a logistic regression in scikit-learn.

however, I am not getting them ordered correctly after applying OrdinalEncoder() - where the salary is 'high' I am getting a '0' while it should be '2'.

```
oe = OrdinalEncoder()
df[["salary"]] = oe.fit_transform(df[["salary"]])
df

    department  salary  tenure
0   operations  1.0     5
1   operations  2.0     6
2   support     2.0     6
3   logics      0.0     8
4   sales       0.0     5
```

I know that I can use df["salary"] = df["salary"].replace(0,3) but I'm hoping maybe someone can advise of a more direct way to do it. thank  you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform this operation using `OrdinalEncoder`, you can use the `categories` parameter to specify the ordering.

As follows:

```
OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['low', 'medium', 'high']]).fit_transform(df[['salary']])
```

Output:

```
array([[0.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [2.],
       [2.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

As @BENY says, you can stay in pandas and do what you want. `factorize` is great if "low" appears first, "medium" second and "high" third in the data (as shown in your example). If that's not the case, `factorize` may not produce what you want.

A possible solution is to create a dictionary that maps salary levels to numbers and use `map`:

```
mapper = dict([['low', 1], ['medium', 2], ['high', 3]])
df['salary'] = df['salary'].map(mapper)
```

Output:

```
   department  salary  tenure
0  operations       1       5
1  operations       2       6
2     support       2       6
3      logics       3       8
4       sales       3       5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just stay with pandas `factorize`

```
df['new'] = df.salary.factorize()[0]
#Out[276]: array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int64)
```